# sql in postgres

Tags: sql, asp.net, postgresql

```
select * from
(select child as enfant,title as libelle, COALESCE(parent ,child) as Parent  
from tree2) as tree2  
order by COALESCE(parent , 1),parent,enfant
```

I wrote this query in my postgres and it works but when i use it in my program asp c# it doesn't return anything , like he don t have any data 
what is the problem any help thnks and sory for my english

Comment: Well it sounds like the C# code is the problem then.  What happens when you run the query from C#?

Comment: Please include your C# code also so we can see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(select child as enfant,title as libelle, COALESCE(parent ,child) as Parent  
from tree2) as tree2  
order by COALESCE(parent , 1),parent,enfant
```

Is the same as...

```
select child as enfant, title as libelle, COALESCE(parent ,child) as Parent  
from tree2
order by parent NULLS LAST, enfant NULLS LAST
```

But no idea on the C# that's another question we can't just figure out the problem there without any information.

Answer (score 0):

salam 
 is weird but i solve it just ,it was a problem in my c# code 
any way thnks

for the query 
"select child as enfant, title as libelle, COALESCE(parent ,child) as Parent
from tree2
order by parent NULLS LAST, enfant NULLS LAST"
yeas is the same i try it it and it pretty clear with urs thnks